# EXCEL: Return value from row where id matches and date is the latest

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I would appreciate your help creating the following EXCEL formula. I have two sheets: assets and transactions.

In the **ASSETS sheet**, each asset has a unique id. It looks like this:

```
A      C      ...  H
------------------------
ID    ASSET      WHERE
1     ntbk       [formula]
2     tablet     [formula]
3     headset    [formula]
```

In the **TRANS sheets** there are records of transactions for each asset. However, each asset has multiple transaction records.

```
   A           E          G
--------------------------------
AssetID    TransDate    Where
   1       20161101     storage
   3       20161103     Johnny B. Good
   1       20161106     Joe Smith
```

I need to determine the **[formula]** which would return the value from TRANS sheet column E where ID matches and the date is the latest. Basically, I need to know where the asset is now. So far, I haven't been successful. I'd appreciate your help.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Use this array formula:

```
=INDEX(TRANS!$E$2:$E$1000,MAX(IF(TRANS!$A$2:$A$1000=B2,ROW(TRANS!$C$2:$C$1000)-ROW(INDEX(TRANS!$C$2:$C$1000,1,1))+1)))
```

Put it, press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> and fill down

Comment: Thanks for your input. However, the formula doesn't work properly. It displays value from the latest record in TRANS sheet, not value from the row with the latest date :/

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested, this is how I resolved it using simple formulas:

Created new hidden column in the **TRANS sheet** combining id and date of each operation:

```
=IF(A2="";"";"id" & A2 & "date" & E2)
```

Then, I created two hidden columns in the **ASSETS sheet**. 
Column F to find most recent date for the itemID:

```
{=IF(A2="";"";MAX(IF(trans!$A$2:$A$1000=assets!A2;trans!$E$2:$E$1000)))}
```

Column G to combine itemID and corresponding most recent date:

```
=IF(A2="";"";"id" & A2 & "date" & F2)
```

Finally, the I was able to use VLOOKUP for **[formula]** I was looking for to tell me where is the item now:

```
=IF(A42="";"";VLOOKUP(G42;trans!$B$2:$G$1000;6;FALSE))
```